# Setup pagename in SSRS R2 when export to Excel

Tags: ssrs-2008

I've to put sheetnames when export my SSRS to excel for each pagebreak. I read the documentation and I couldn't get the PageName properties in my tablix properties. 
I checked in group properties as well but only I can setup page breaks options between instances of a group

I'm working with SSRS R2. Is this alloe only for Report builder?

someone can help me!!!

Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PageName property is available in the report designer (BIDS) also. You won't find it when you right click on the 
report item and choose properties. Instead, look in the properties window for the tablix.

One other thing you may want to check is the Target Server Version property for the project. As you know this is only in
SQL2008R2. So, you won't see it if the target server version is set to SQL2008 or prior versions.

~Sam.